# Combine all x titles on sub plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to combine all of these titles into one centered in the middle, but after doing research I couldn't find the right parameter or anything.

[image]

Here is my code:

```py
    fig = px.bar(total_df, x="year", y="cases", facet_col="county_type", color="stage", text='cases', )
    fig.update_traces(cliponaxis=False)
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text = f'Number of Cases of {specified_cancer} Cancer with County Type (2019-2020)',
        yaxis_title="Total Cases",
        legend_title="Stage"
    )

    for anno in fig['layout']['annotations']:
        anno['text'] = str(anno['text']).replace('county_type=', '')


    fig.show()
```

if anyone could help it would be awesome!

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but in this case, since there are three Facet graphs, it is accomplished by making the first and last x-axes untitled. `fig.layout.xaxis.title.text = None;fig.layout.xaxis3.title.text = None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Have you checked the docs here:
https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations?

Add this code to you code, replace your for loop, and see if it works:

```
# filter out annotations that contain the text 'year='
annotations = [anno for anno in fig['layout']['annotations'] if 'year=' not in anno['text']]

# Add centered year subtitle
annotations.append(
    dict(
        x=0.5,
        y=1.05, # adjust if needed
        showarrow=False,
        text="Year",
        xref="paper",
        yref="paper",
        font=dict(size=15),
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="top"
    )
)

# add the modified annotations list (which includes the original annotations, excluding ones with 'year=') and the new centered "Year" annotation.
fig['layout']['annotations'] = annotations
```

Answer (score 1):

In the update_layout method configure the X-axis options to the following to remove duplicates

```
xaxis = dict(title = "Year", showticklabels = True, dtick = 1), 
xaxis2 = dict(showticklabels = False),
```